# How do I encode a binary MIME attachment in C#?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, mime

I need to send a binary attachment to a JAVA webservice via SwA (Soap with Attachments). After discovering that .Net does not support SwA I am writing my own client. How do I encode the binary MIME attachment, so that the Java service will be able to decode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: you don't encode it. It is simply added as raw bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the various MIME RFC, mostly it uses Base64 which thankfully .NET already handles.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old, but others may be looking for a similar answer.

Are you sure you need to write your own client - .NET WSE has support for MTOM for a long time, and MTOM was designed to be backward compatible with SwA.. I would look into this and try MTOM before attempting to write my own client.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx) and [System.Net.Mime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.aspx) namespaces.  Some of the work there may be done for you.
Particularly look at [System.Net.Mail.Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx).